# Kendo UI grid command.imageClass is missing in ASP MVC helper

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Many pure html samples are referring and using Kendo UI grid's command's 
imageClass property:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: myDataSource,
columns: [
    {
        command: { 
            name: "Edit",
            text:"",
            imageClass: "k-icon k-i-pencil ob-icon-only",
            click: function(e) {
                //some code
            }
        }
    },
    ...
],
```

});

I am using Kendo UI ASP MVC version and it seems to not have this property to set. What am I missing?

In case this is really missing (I hope not), still how can I set this property even in javascript? (I would like to keep my html helper rendering and not doing *everything* in javascript, that solution is obvious...)

[image]

Comment: A very aggravating thing about finding Kendo help is that you have to be careful to stay away from "Kendo UI" solutions because "Kendo MVC" is different, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 1):

You would not use imageClass in the MVC Helper; you would use the HtmlAttributes property. You may define it like so:

```
columns.Command(o => o.Edit().Text("")
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-icon k-i-pencil ob-icon-only" }));
```

Good luck.

Edit: Why not modify the css to accomodate that?

```
.ob-icon-only span{ }
```

Regarding adding the kendo classes to the inner span element, you could do that on databound and modify the element accordingly.

Comment: I've tried already that solution, before I asked for ImageClass. Unfortunatelly the class attributes must added to the _inner_ span class. Adding those classes to the button (outer <a> element) causes incorrect rendering the button.

Comment: about kryptonkal edit: This case I must copy and paste the same CSS from kendo and/or bootstrap what is defined originally for k-icon. I think it is not a professional solution to copy an paste CSS to a new selector instead trying to apply the original class.

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way to specify custom styles is to use the auto generated `k-grid-NAME_OF_COMMAND` class. If this is not suitable in the current implementation, I would suggest you to bind to the dataBound event and attach the class there. Use the `OnCancel` event to replace the icon again after cancelling an edit.

**Examples**

```
.Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound").Cancel("onCancel"))
```

*JavaScript*

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    $(".k-grid-NAME_OF_COMMAND").addClass("k-icon k-i-pencil ob-icon-only");
}
```

Or

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    $(".k-grid-edit").find("span").removeClass("k-icon k-edit");
    $(".k-grid-edit").find("span").addClass("k-icon k-i-pencil ob-icon-only");
}
```

Add the cancel event to ensure the icon stays when cancelling an edit.

```
function onCancel(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.sender.refresh();
}
```

**Result**

[image: Edit Icon]

**Other test**

Using `$(".k-grid-edit").find("span").addClass("k-icon k-i-cancel ob-icon-only");`

[image: Cancel Icon]

Comment: Vash: Many thanks for the detailed answers. I've already used your _second_ solution for my custom button. (the first is not correct, because the image is implemented by the inner span) but were not satisfied for the following reasons: If inline edit enabled in grid, then pressing [Edit] then [Cancel] the custom button hided, then recreated and this deletes the classes from the inner span. I've tried to utilize the Cancel event to patch back the class attributes, but unfortunately the custom button still hided when the Cancel event runs, so obviously the jQuery will find nothing...

Comment: Added to my prev comment: Interestingly pressing edit button, then update button will not delete the classes from the custom buttons's inner span. Only the pressing edit button then pressing cancel buttons sequence deletes the span's classes. Both cases the custom button is hided, so I do not know what could be the difference... (edit: yes I know: After edit a databound event also runs, so that reapplies the classes)

Comment: Ive edited my response but it seems like it may be the same approach as here. You may have to override all of the events or modify the kendo js source.

Comment: I made a mistake in the original code, using Edit instead of edit in the CSS selector. Using the Cancel event you can ensure the icon stays if you cancel an edit.

Comment: a) As I wrote I've tried even before I asked the question here, but unfortunatelly when the Cancel event fires the custom button actually does not exist, so the jQuery select obviously not finding it. b) Overwriting original  sources: that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I do not think it is professional, not talking about handling upgrades, when new version of the sources should be applied (I mean kendo or bootstrap)

Comment: `$(".k-grid-edit")` should find your button. At least it does in my test application. Combined with `e.preventDefault(); e.sender.refresh();` in the cancel event handler it should keep your new icon.

Comment: First off you can't add classes to commands in that way.  It makes logical sense, but when the button HTML gets rendered it already puts CSS classes into the style and yours get ditched.  Secondly, regarding this particular solution, who is to say you only want the image when an action like Cancel (or any other action) occurs?  I want the page to render with the buttons in place and an image sitting on them.  That should not be difficult.  In fact the Kendo UI actually has an "Icon" property you can set with a string.  But not Kendo MVC.